# Decoding string received from the server

Tags: android, utf-8, decode

An Android app receives some text from a server, the text should be shown for the user as a message of an `AlertDialog`. The text is a part of a JSON that the client receives in a response.
The text is translated into several languages, which the app supports, and for some languages the text is unreadable. For example:
`"ÐœÑƒÐ·Ñ‹ÐºÐ°"` instead of `"Музыка"`.
I tried to decode the string: 
`URLDecoder.decode("ÐœÑƒÐ·Ñ‹ÐºÐ°", "UTF-8")`
but that didn't help. The method returned the same `"ÐœÑƒÐ·Ñ‹ÐºÐ°"`. 
Neither helped 
`URLEncoder.encode("ÐœÑƒÐ·Ñ‹ÐºÐ°", "UTF-8")`
 it returned `"%C3%90%C5%93%C3%91%C6%92%C3%90%C2%B7%C3%91%E2%80%B9%C3%90%C2%BA%C3%90%C2%B0"`.
How can I make it readable, and display `"Музыка"` instead of `"ÐœÑƒÐ·Ñ‹ÐºÐ°"`?

Comment: How do you parse the JSON response ?

Comment: I'm using Gson library:
`new Gson().fromJson(json, Struct.class)`

Comment: Are you sure that the server properly encodes the strings with utf8 ?